# Linq to Entities any way to regenerate only the changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to update a `CART`.  When I am doing the search for it, it fails.  It used a `GUID` since the user is not logon. I don't know if I have to re-update the `DBEntities` maybe ?  not sure.

I got this error :  `The specified type member 'CartId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Thanks

ShoppingCart.cs

```
 namespace Tp1WebStore3.Models
 {
     public partial class ShoppingCart
     {
         Tp1WebStoreDBEntities db = new Tp1WebStoreDBEntities();

         string ShoppingCartId { get; set; }

         public const string CartSessionKey = "CartId";

         public static ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContextBase context)
         {
             var cart = new ShoppingCart();
             cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId(context);
             return cart;
         }

         // Helper method to simplify shopping cart calls
         public static ShoppingCart GetCart(Controller controller)
         {
             return GetCart(controller.HttpContext);
         }

         public void AddToCart(Produit produit)
         {
             // Get the matching cart and album instances
             var cartItem = db.Paniers.SingleOrDefault(
                 c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId &&
                      c.ProduitId == produit.ProduitId);   <== the error happen here
```

Panier.cs

```
 namespace Tp1WebStore3.Models
 {
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;

     public partial class Panier
     {
         public int PanierId { get; set; }
         public string CartId { get; set; }
         public int ProduitId { get; set; }
         public int Quantite { get; set; }
         public decimal Prix { get; set; }

         public System.DateTime DateCree { get; set; }

         public virtual Produit Produit { get; set; }
     }
  }
```

produit.cs

```
 namespace Tp1WebStore3.Models
 {
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;

     public partial class Produit
     {
         public Produit()
         {
             this.Paniers = new HashSet<Panier>();
         }

         public int ProduitId { get; set; }
         public int CategorieId { get; set; }
         public string Description { get; set; }
         public int Quantite { get; set; }
         public decimal Prix { get; set; }

         public virtual Categorie Categorie { get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<Panier> Paniers { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

Comment: If you changed things in the database you have to update the Data model. Right click inside your .edmx file where your entity diagram is and click Update model from db

Comment: @CSharper  I am trying to perform what you said but I cannot select the tables box ? any idea?

Comment: @CSharper  If you want you can put your solution.  It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed things in the database you have to update the Data model. Right click inside your .edmx file where your entity diagram is and click Update model from db